# what is the best practice to add new field to an api route

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, theme-development, rest-api

I'm modifying the WP REST API for mobile app usage, and I went through at the first registering new fields route using the `rest_api_init` action or hook using the func `register_rest_field`, but I found there's a lot of fields I don't need it or wanted so I get rid of it by using the filter `rest_prepare_post`

What I found out is I can actually add new fields in my filter by modifying the **data array** and no needs for the `rest_api_init` or `register_rest_field` at all.

So what I am asking is what is the best approach for doing this? is it good to add and remove fields in one function instead of two? I'm now using both `register_route_field` for the new fields and `unset` all the unnecessary `fields` by `rest_prepare_post`

Comment: I don't understand why you need to unset fields you don't want. Just don't register them if you don't want them. Unless you're storing all the fields in a single meta value?

Comment: WordPress gives a lot of fields out of the box I don't need on the REST API like `date_gmt` for example so I just deleted and not only that the reasons I used the `rest_prepare_post ` but also for customizing the response, however, I need to be. anyway, my question is why I should use `register_rest_field ` when the `rest_prepare_post` filter doing the same job and less code, what is the best practice?